# C# client can't connect to server with port 8080

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

Why my client can't connect to the server with port 8080. I use vpn to set network lan But port 80 is working fine.

When I connect to site by ip in port 8080. it's return This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.

How can i fix it.

my server is iis7.

[image]

Comment: Firewall perhaps?

Comment: already closed. and already open port 8080.

Comment: Is the port accessible from your PC?

Comment: server side port 8080 working fine. but client side (my pc) can't connect.

Comment: You need to capture packets on both side (browser/IIS) to track down where the TCP RESET comes from. BTW, IIS 7.x has been end of life for a while so don't expect it to work very well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try adding firewall rules. On the site's server, go to Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, select Inbound Rules and add a new rule specifying port 8080 for all connections.